# class-transformer's plainToClass: How to use this function to convert the plain literal to an abstract class?

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, class-transformer

Whenever I call plainToClass as so:

```
someClass: SomeClass = plainToClass(SomeClass, somePlain)
```

Everything is fine. But once I change SomeClass to be abstract and rewrite the above as:

```
someAbstractClass: SomeAbstractClass = plainToClass(SomeAbstractClass, somePlain)
```

I get the error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(cls: ClassType<BaseFeature>, plain: unknown[], options?: ClassTransformOptions): BaseFeature[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof BaseFeature' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClassType<BaseFeature>'.
      Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(cls: ClassType<SomeAbstractClass>, plain: object, options?: ClassTransformOptions): SomeAbstractClass', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'typeof SomeAbstractClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClassType<SomeAbstractClass>'
```

Is it not possible do use plainToClass to convert the plain to an abstractClass instance? Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a normal class and an abstract class have different signatures in TS:

```js
export interface AbstractType<T> extends Function {
  prototype: T;
}

export type Type<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
```

And due to this difference TS shows the error.

Usually there shouldn't be instances of abstract classes, only instances of classes that implemented them. Nevertheless you can hack it with `any` and get desired behavior:

```js
const someAbstractClass: SomeAbstractClass = plainToClass(
  SomeAbstractClass as any, // cast to fix the error.
  somePlain,
);
```